# Create a valid APK file for Google PlayStore

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to create a .apk file in android studio to upload to the google play store.

I have already used

> build > generate signed bundle/apk

however this seems to only create a .jks file which cannot be uploaded to the google play store.

Is there a step that I am missing?

Comment: Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK _should_ allow you build a release build you can upload. Please explain your issue in more detail (_exactly_ what are you seeing). See here for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK > APK** in this area will help you to create a release APK that can be used to upload an app in Google PlayStore.

This link will also help you to create an app for Google Playstore https://developer.android.com/studio/publish

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response but I figured out what was confusing me; I had gotten to this page [C:\Users*username*\Documents\Switch_Slider.jks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO3gn.png) and assumed the .apk file would be stored at the location given on that page, when it was only the .jks file and the .apk would be stored at this location [C:\Users*username*\Documents\Programming Projects\SwitchSlider\SwitchSlider\app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iboRU.png)